# Error conexión a AWS via SSH desde terminal

Tags: aws, macos, ssh

Cuando establezco la conexión con AWS via SSH me arroja este error "no such identity: ruta-donde-guardaste-tu-llave-privada: No such file or directory" y no hace la conexión. Estoy usando macOS

Answer (score 0):

Asegurarse que se haga correctamente el cambio de permisos a la lave .pem.

chmod 400 `millave.pem`